# Facebook graph's safe average request time not to get rate limited

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I was running some queries using Facebook graph php sdk and noticed in my dashboard showing little bit high average requests time of **3,206ms** for some queries with respect to other queries.Is that high? What is the safe request time that we should maintain not to get rate limited ?

Comment: It totally depends on what query you are making. And request time doesn't matter when it comes to rate limiting

Comment: @WizKid so average request time has nothing to do with total_time and total_cputime in the rate limiting header ?I thought they are related and that's why its shown as one of the serious factors in dashboard.

Comment: Request time you measure includes network back and forth to Facebook. That doesn't matter. Yes CPU usage matter.